# selenium test is failing using selenium javascript webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I have installed `javascript` `selenium webdriver` and write a first test like this

I am writing a test for login. I enter correct username and password and try to login.

```
describe('Checkout Google.com', function () {
let driver;
before(async function () {
    // driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
});
it('Search on Google', async function () {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    await driver.get('http://alpdev.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/');
    // await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('selenium', Key.RETURN);
    this.timeout(5000);
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Email']")).sendKeys('owais@demoshop.com');
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']")).sendKeys('test');
    await driver.findElement(By.className('btn-submit')).click().then(()=> done());
    // assert.equal(title, 'dalenguyen - Google Search');
   });
    // close the browser after running tests
    after(() => driver && driver.quit());
 })
```

And my package json is like this

```
{
   "name": "selenium-01",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
     "test": "mocha --recursive index.js"
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies": {
     "mocha": "^7.2.0",
     "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.7"
   }
}
```

Now when i run `ng run test` so browser opens and test is passed visually meaning that login is happening but on console it prints like this

[image]

What's wrong here that it's giving an error.

Answer (score 1):

So, I could not fully reproduce your case as the **url** in the script is not available anymore but found a few flaws though and tried some fixes.

First is your `driver` was declared twice.

Second, I believe the main problem (the reason you are getting the error mentioned above) is that you're using the `then` & `done` promises which are not needed as you're using the `async` & `await` functions.

Also I would recommend you use the **css** locators instead of the **xpaths**.

Another thing is you could use the `async` in the `after();` closure, and you could use the arrow functions `(async () => {});` all around instead of using the *function* keyword.

Below is your example but with a few changes and I am quite positive it will work (though if this is all on the google search page, there are no inputs on that page so those steps will fail, you'll have to add some extra steps to load the login page with the input fields available):

```
describe('Checkout Google.com', function () {
    let driver;
    before(async () => {
        driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    });

    it('Search on Google', async () => {
        await driver.get('http://alpdev.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/');
        await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('selenium', Key.RETURN);
        await driver.sleep(5000);

        // the steps below will fail as per the description above
        await driver.findElement(By.css("input[placeholder='Email']")).sendKeys('owais@demoshop.com');
        await driver.findElement(By.css("input[placeholder='Password']")).sendKeys('test');
        await driver.findElement(By.className('btn-submit')).click();
        // assert.equal(title, 'dalenguyen - Google Search');
    });

    // close the browser after running tests
    after(async () => {
        await driver.quit();
    });
});
```

I hope this helps, please let me know.